# Particles dispersion from one object to another

Tags: particles

Is it possible to control particles that they would form one object and after some kind of particle dispersion they would form another object. For example from cube particle fly and form cylinder form.

[image]

Comment: There is also an [addon](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?263719-Particle-Morphing-Tools-%28First-Part-Updated%29) for creating effects like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you would need to add a particle system to the cube as well as the cylinder, after that you create a controlling object (the plane in my example) and add both particle systems as key targets to the keys in the physics tab where *Keyed* must be enabled.

[image]

When you play the animation <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> the particles move from the first key to the next (you can have more than two of them).

[image]

Documentation [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Physics/Keyed)

Answer (score 5):

You can add a curve guide to specify the path the particles will follow between the two objects.

[image]

Then for something fancy you can you can give the guide a braid kink to have it swirl around the curve on the way.

[image]

Comment: This Curve Guide via Force Field is new to me. Thank you for sharing this.